# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.internal.XMLTypeIntf exception displayed when i execute the code?

Tags: java, database, eclipse, jdbc, jar

I tried to get the xml value from database and display in the text box,but when i execute the code getting the below exception when i execute the code,

similarly i tried to get the string value(text) from database to and display in the text box its working fine.problem with XMLType and the exceptions.

I am executing the code using the eclipse application and included the jars **xdb6,ojdbc14,xmlparserv2**

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   oracle/jdbc/internal/XMLTypeIntf  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   oracle.xdb.XMLTypeFactory.create(XMLTypeFactory.java:74)  at
>   oracle.sql.OPAQUE.toClass(OPAQUE.java:376)    at
>   oracle.sql.OPAQUE.toJdbc(OPAQUE.java:318)     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java:144)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java:100)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getObject(OracleResultSetImpl.java:915)
>     at Searchdb.actionPerformed(Searchdb.java:327)  at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.internal.XMLTypeIntf    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 55 more

```
String strxa = tfx1.getText(); //here i will get the student id from user.

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:1521/service","username","pwd");
    Statement st =con.createStatement();
    String str3 ="select student_xml  from student where student_id='"+strxa+"'";

    System.out.println(str3);

    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(str3);
    System.out.println(str3);

   if (rs.next()) {

            XMLType poxml = (XMLType)rs.getObject(1);
            System.out.println(poxml); //when i try to print this no output in console
            String poString =poxml.getStringVal();
            System.out.println(poString); when i try to print this no output in console


            //Sets Records in TextFields.
            area.setText(poString);


        }
```

Is there any problem with my jars or code.when i tried to print the value inside the while loop its not getting printed in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error says to me that you are using incompatible versions of the xdb and ojdbc JARs.

According to your stacktrace, the class `oracle.xdb.XMLTypeFactory` (which is in the xdb JAR) depends on the class `oracle.jdbc.internal.XMLTypeIntf`.  This latter class can be found in the 12c versions of the JDBC driver JARs, which can be downloaded from [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html), but not in versions of the JDBC driver older than that.

Either upgrade ojdbc to a later version, or downgrade xdb to an older version.

Comment: I have reduce the xdb version with xdb6 into xdb, then used the ojdbc6 jar with xmlparserv2 jar.its working fine thanks @Luke Woodward